# How to count unique entries withing data validated cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a userform to input into an excel cell from a data validated list. Meaning. On the userform I start typing a location and it populates the userform then the data gets put into a cell. Now the question...How can I have that column on excel count and give me the number of locations without adding in the duplicate values. Can i do it inserting a function on a cell within excel or do I need a macro of sorts. Any suggestions how I can get a function to determine the number of different locations?
I searched and I am not sure if this was ever asked before.  Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the size of your data this can take a while to calculate, but this array formula will give you the number of unique entries in a range.

```
=SUM(1/COUNTIF(A1:A10,A1:A10))
```

Where A1:A10 is the actual range containing your data, of course. You must confirm the formula with ctrl+shift+enter. Or, in VBA, it's

```
Range.FormulaArray = "=SUM(1/COUNTIF(A1:A10,A1:A10))"
```

Edit: To account for empty cells try this:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(1/IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A1:A10)),COUNTIF(A1:A10,A1:A10)),""))
```

Again entered as an array formula.

Comment: Something happens since those are populated from a data validated list...Says divisible by zero error. Anything else I need to look for?

Comment: Oh and it might be a max of 38 rows in a single column, so its not that much to count.

Comment: What if the number of cells in a column are different for various sheets? Seems I am getting the divisible by zero error if there is an empty number of cells in the column. Does this formula work only if all the cells have a value in them?

Comment: I actually didn't realize this, but yes, the formula doesn't work if there are empty cells. Edited with an alternative that accounts for empty cells.